# Uno Platform - WASM - is there a way to read/interact with the address bar of the browser?

Tags: uwp, webassembly, uno-platform

I'm new to Uno Platform and WebAsssembly in general, but think it has great potential!

Is there a way to read from and interact with the browser's address bar from an Uno Platform app running in WebAssembly (similar to HTML5's `history` object?). The examples I've seen do not do this.

FOR EXAMPLE: the user types in: `http://myUnoApp.com/home`  Can I read the `/home` part? Or if he goes to the "Home" page of my app, can I set the browser's address bar to `http://myUnoApp.com/home`? And can I read the history so if he presses the back button of the browser, my app knows where to go?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question and should be reopened

Comment: I know.  I don't know what's unclear about it.  Maybe an example will help.

Comment: Please add one, it was closed by a JS moderator, maybe he didn't understand the question properly, as it is regarding Uno. I have voted to reopen it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can invoke JavaScript:

```cs
var url = WebAssemblyRuntime.InvokeJS("window.location.href");
```

Comment: That's what I needed!